# Error in maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config

I have above error on call webservice function (for example GetUserInfo). this function returns alot of data but not more than 65KB also i set maxReceivedMessageSize to 2000000000  on my config in client. ServiceModel of my config file is :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="AAAServerSoap12Binding">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2000000000" maxWritePoolSize="2000000000"
        messageVersion="Soap12">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2000000000"
          maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000000"  maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"
        maxBufferSize="2000000000" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
 </bindings>
 <client>
  <endpoint address="http://10.187.110.5:8280/services/AAAServer.AAAServerHttpSoap12Endpoint"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AAAServerSoap12Binding"
    contract="AAAServiceReference.AAAServerPortType" name="AAAServerHttpSoap12Endpoint"  />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

every time i got this error i save xml result of GetUserInfo to a file and that file was 24KB - 50KB) , and never reaches to 65KB or more. Error is

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element. ---> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

thanks

Comment: i solved my problem by add maxReceivedMessageSize=200000000 && maxBufferPoolSize="2000000000" in server side in service-web.config and then add to client too.

Comment: Your approach is correct just keep in mind that 200,000,000 bytes is equal to 190MB, you better hope you never get a request that large unless you have some serious processing power. Maybe make it 100,000,000 which is still large.

Comment: thanks Namphibian, you are right

Comment: Keep in mind with a extremely large accepted size people can launch denial of service attacks on your service.

Comment: what is your mean? did you mean if i limited sent data from service this attacks dont occur???

Comment: No setting this value high will allow a attacker to send very large badly formed packets which will make it easier to carry out a DOS attack. A lower value means they will have to send a lot more packets before a security system realises what goes on. If I could carry out a DOS attack with a 200MB XML request it is easy. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: very thanks for your comments